# Why can't JPA entity classes can have custom instance variables?

Tags: java, jpa

Suppose that I have a JPA entity class named `Photo` for storing photos. I also have another non-entity class named `PhotoStatus` to hold these count informations such as `shareCount`, `likeCount`, and `commentCount`. Now, if add an instance variable(`private PhotoStatus status;`) to the entity class `Photo`to hold these status information, The following error message is shown:

> Basic attributes can only be of the following types: Java primitive
>   types, wrapper of primitive types, String, java.math.BigInteger,
>   java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar,
>   java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.TimeStamp, byte[], Byte[],
>   char[], Character[], enums, or any Serializable type.

Why it is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want JPA to ignore that particular property, you should give it the `@Transient` annotation (and then manage it yourself); if you want it persisted, you should make `PhotoStatus` a proper entity.

Comment: ... or provide a TypeConverter for that type to define how it will be persisted, or make it implement Serializable

Answer (score 2):

If you read this part of the error message, you'll get your answer.

> or any Serializable type.

Your custom class(`PhotoStatus`) needs to implement the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: @Jomoos - No prob!:) Happens to everybody:)

Comment: Technically correct, but i'd strongly advise against storing serialized java objects in a database - this is almost always an design mistake, IMHO...

Comment: @GyroGearless - Yeah you're right. But I'm really not sure what the OP is trying to do here. Hence, refrained from suggesting to use `@Transient`. #Jomoos - If feasible, you must consider using the `@Transient` for fields which you don't intend to persist.

Comment: Yep! I too feel `transient` is more apt in my case.

Answer (score 1):

try to add @Transient in your getter method

```
@Transient
public PhotoStatus getStatus() { 
  return status;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely `PhotoStatus` is an `@Embeddable`:

```
@Entity
public class Photo {
    ...
    private PhotoStatus status;
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class PhotoStatus {
    private int shareCount;
    private int likeCount;
    private int commentCount;
}
```

By default this will map the `PhotoStatus` fields to the columns with the same names in `Photo`'s table. To allow you to use an embeddable in multiple entities, you can override the default column names in the entity:

```
@Entity
public class Photo {
    ...
    @AttributeOverride(name="shareCount", column=@Column(name = "SHARE"))
    private PhotoStatus status;
    ...
}
```